# How do I test ruby eval() using rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec, sandbox

I am creating a ruby sandbox environment. I am using eval() to evaluate the code and using the rubycop gem to ensure safety. How do I test the output of the code using rspec. For example a user types in the code, i evaluate it. How do i run the result against a rspec test?

For example i ask the user to create an add method, once i get the output run eval(code) on it. I write an rspec test.

```
describe "#add" do 
  it "should equal the sum of two numbers" do 
    add(2, 3).should eq 5
  end
end
```

How do i run this code and get the result on the backend.

Comment: using `expect`? e.g. `expect{eval('User.create')}.to change{User.count}.by(1)`

Comment: What kind of assertions do you need to make for your sandbox? Are you just wanting to ensure a call to `object.method` inside the sandbox environment is equivalent to a direct call to the same - in effect assertions about the sandbox environment? Or are the tests being run interactively by the users of the sandbox?